# Globalize 3 on production server not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, globalize3

I am trying to use Globalize3 gem for model translations to Active Record i.e. internationalization for database. After going through the documentation, I was able to implement it successfully on local server in both development and production environment.
But when i try to implement it on a production Server, it fails. It shows absurd behavior, i.e. it works and sometime doesn't.
Trying to set locale via user input. 
Using this below function to set locale.

```
def set_language
    if params[:locale]    
      I18n.default_locale = params[:locale]
    end
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

[link to globalize3 gem documentation](https://github.com/svenfuchs/globalize3)

Answer (score 0):

You're only setting the fallback locale with that code. It'll probably help to adjust the current locale, too, as in

```
def set_language
    if params[:locale]    
      I18n.default_locale = params[:locale]
      I18n.locale = params[:locale]
    end
    redirect_to :back
end
```

Comment: thank you for your support but it doesn't solve my problem :(